# Remove GET variables from URL in python

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, url, python-2.7

I have this URL :

```
http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php?a=jsd
```

and what i want the output is something like this :

```
http://www.exmaple.com/boo/
```

like wise if i have

```
http://www.exmaple.com/abc.html
```

it should be

```
http://www.exmaple.com/
```

and

```
http://www.exmaple.com/
```

should return

```
http://www.exmaple.com/
```

without any change

**This is what i have tried**

```
re.sub(r'\?[\S]+','',"http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php?a=jsd")
```

**but it returns**

```
http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php
```

Any suggestions what could be done to get the correct output or does anyone have any better ideas to get this done ?

Comment: Is the [`urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) not good enough?

Comment: Is it 'exmaple' everywhere on purpose?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes url parse was what i needed!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php?a=jsd"
>>> url[:url.rfind("/")+1]
'http://www.exmaple.com/boo/'
```

To remove everything that is after the last "/". I am not sure it covers all special cases though...

**EDIT**: New solution using `urlparse` and my simple `rfind`:

```
import re, urlparse
def url_cutter(url):
    up = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    url2 = up[0]+"://"+up[1]+up[2]
    if url.rfind("/")>6:
            url2 = url2[:url2.rfind("/")+1]
    return url2
```

Then:

```
In [36]: url_cutter("http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php?a=jsd")
Out[36]: 'http://www.exmaple.com/boo/'

In [37]: url_cutter("http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php?a=jsd#dvt_on")
Out[37]: 'http://www.exmaple.com/boo/'

In [38]: url_cutter("http://www.exmaple.com")
Out[38]: 'http://www.exmaple.com'
```

Comment: Indeed @MevinBabu, one can add a simple test like `if url.rfind("/")>6` to avoid this case.

Comment: It fails if the url has `#fragment/with/slashes`

Answer (score 5):

Please, use the stdlib `urlparse` module, like this. Generally, I try to avoid regex unless it is absolutely necessary.

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse
>>> parsed = urlparse("http://www.exmaple.com/boo/a.php?a=jsd")
>>> scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = parsed
>>> urlunparse((scheme,netloc,path.split('/')[1],'','',''))
'http://www.exmaple.com/boo'
```

Comment: Yes, however, the `path.split` part requires some tune-up (check out `http://www.exmaple.com/`).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more optimized way to do it but with this one you won't need an obscure import or third party package.

```
url = "http://www.google.com/abc/abc.html?q=test"
cleaned_url = url[:url.rindex("?")]
cleaned_url = cleaned_url.split("/")
cleaned_url = [item for item in cleaned_url if ".html" not in item]
cleaned_url = "/".join(cleaned_url)
```

Comment: You might want to test if url.rindex sends you back an error in case "?" is not present in the string